# how to handle clicks for such these image buttons ui objects?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How to make two imageViews and ask user to select one of them (for example ) as gender and on selection the imageView changes its background and if clicked again it returns to normal background

like this ImageViews:

[image: like this ImageViews]

Comment: You can try to help if you can write more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better way, but this is the most basic approach. Here's MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean mMaleImgClicked, mFemaleImgClicked;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView maleImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.male_imageview);
        final ImageView femaleImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.female_imageview);

        maleImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mMaleImgClicked) {
                    maleImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.female_image);

                    mMaleImgClicked = true;
                } else {
                    maleImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.male_image);

                    mMaleImgClicked = false;
                }
            }
        });
        femaleImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mFemaleImgClicked) {
                    femaleImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.male_image);

                    mFemaleImgClicked = true;
                } else {
                    femaleImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.female_image);

                    mFemaleImgClicked = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

... and activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/male_imageview"
        android:src="@drawable/male_image"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/female_imageview"
        android:src="@drawable/female_image"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a setColorFilter in each imageview when you click, just add to the imageview `onClick`:

```
  imageview.setColorFilter(Color.argb(50, 0, 0, 0));
```